# Flutter divide a long text with images

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am creating a news App which i the content of the news is more than 2000 words, my problem is, i want to divide the content and put images in between them.
something like this

Note:

Both the images and text are coming from firebase...

i want to able to do irrespective the length of the words

[image: here]

Comment: Have 2 String variables, create a method that decides if you wanna split the text. If yes, set the value of first String for the first part, the second String for the second part, then: `Column(children: [Text(firstPart), Image(), if (secondPart != null) Text(secondPart])`

Comment: i understhand this logic, but the text is coming from firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can use **RichText** widget for this types of complex UI.

```
RichText( 
   text: TextSpan( 
      children: [ 
        TextSpan( text: "Some Text...", ), 
        WidgetSpan( child: 
          Image.network(src), 
        ), 
        TextSpan( text: "Some Text...", ), 
      ], 
   ), 
),
```

Comment: i am going to edit the question

Comment: i understand this logic, but the text is coming from firebase

Answer (score 0):

To cut a big sentence you can use the split method and create a list and save it as 2 different strings like

```dart
List<String> stringList = verylongSentence.split(" ");

  int start = 0;
  int end = 20;//get first 20 words

  /// sublist of stringList
  final joinedWords = stringList.sublist(start, end);
  /// join the list with space
  String _content1 = joinedWords.join(" ");
  String _content2 = stringList.sublist(end).join(" ");
```

Comment: Thanks so much... okay, let me try this logic. i will get back to you